# Combine ConsoleModifiers and ConsoleKey

Tags: c#, console

I'm fairly new to `C#` and I'd appreciate your contribution.

At the moment, I have the following line on my code:
    `while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Q) { } //Exit on Q`

So as you can see, on a Console Application, if the user presses `Q` the application exits. Fine. Now, the question is: is there any way to combine a `ConsoleModifiers` plus `ConsoleKey`? Instead of using the `Q` key, I'd prefer to use the `Ctrl+Q` on exit.

The reason why I want to achieve this is that I don't feel confortable to leave only one key on exit (makes easy to prevent that someone presses it accidently). Altough the syntax is completely incorrect, that's what I roughly would like to achieve:
    `ConsoleModifiers.Control + ConsoleKey.Q`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store ConsoleKeyInfo in variable and check for both parameters.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo c;
while ((c = Console.ReadKey()).Modifiers != ConsoleModifiers.Control
       || c.Key != ConsoleKey.Q) { } //Exit on Ctrl + Q
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

this should do it

```
Func<ConsoleKeyInfo, bool> CheckKey = x => x.Key != ConsoleKey.Q || x.Modifiers != ConsoleModifiers.Control;     
while (CheckKey(Console.ReadKey()))
{

}
```

you have to check the `Key` and the `Control` property

Comment: That's really great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's documentation of the Console.ReadKey() method contains relevant information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx

In particular, ConsoleKeyInfo has a Modifiers member you can test for (where cki is a ConsoleKeyInfo instance):

```
if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0) Console.Write("CTL+");
```

Full code:

```
public static void Main() 
   {
      ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
      // Prevent example from ending if CTL+C is pressed.
      Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

      Console.WriteLine("Press any combination of CTL, ALT, and SHIFT, and a console key.");
      Console.WriteLine("Press the Escape (Esc) key to quit: \n");
      do 
      {
         cki = Console.ReadKey();
         Console.Write(" --- You pressed ");
         if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) != 0) Console.Write("ALT+");
         if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Shift) != 0) Console.Write("SHIFT+");
         if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0) Console.Write("CTL+");
         Console.WriteLine(cki.Key.ToString());
       } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's really worth to have a look at. But in this particular occasion, I'd like to take @M.kazem Akhgary answer.