# Adding values to a string array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, console-application

I am building a calendar. Here I want to add members to my meeting. After every name I want to press enter to add it. When I press, for example <kbd>X</kbd> I want to leave the "add member" process and go to next step, for example, "adding a meeting title".

How can I add members to my array? How can I go to the next step when I'm done entering names? This code doesn't work:

```
Console.Write("Enter members here: ");
memberList = Console.ReadLine();

string[] memberList;
```

Comment: Your code shows a console app, but you're talking about clicking a button... is this a GUI or a console app?

Comment: Console. With 'pressing enter' I mean the keyboard button. I don't know how this works so this was the only logical solution.

Comment: Well it was "When I press f.e. button "X" I want to leave the add member process" - so what do you want happen if the user wants to add a member called X?

Comment: button "X" on keyboard :) @JonSkeet

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think that somebody will add a member called 'x'.

Comment: make it exit when press `Ctrl + X`. someone recently asked this. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345749/combine-consolemodifiers-and-consolekey

Comment: It would be more conventional to stop adding members if the user just hit return, i.e. if they tried to add a member with an *empty* name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use a conditional loop to accomplish this, a `while` loop would work pretty good.

Also, using a `List<string>` would be better in this scenario since you (i) need to add things to it, and (ii) you don't know how big to make the array when you first declare it since you don't know how many names the user will enter.

Something like:

```
var names = new List<string>();
var input = Console.ReadLine();

while (input.ToUpper() != "X")
{
    names.Add(input);
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}


foreach (var name in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

---

If you're wanting to move to the next step immediately after an user presses <kbd>X</kbd> (without them having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>), you can look into using [`Console.ReadKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx) but it'd be more complicated since you'd have to collect one character at a time to get the name and check if they key pressed is <kbd>Enter</kbd>, in which case you'd move on to the next name. There's also the complexity of known when a "X" is just part of someone's name, e.g. Xavier, or whether meant to move on to the next step.

Comment: This looks like how I envisaged the answer. Use a List<> if you want dynamic allocation rather than an array (might want a Console.Write inside the loop there somewhere though)

Comment: When I want to see the result and I write `Console.WriteLine(names);` it says `System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.String]`

Comment: @user5462581 I've updated my answer to show how you'd iterate over the list of names. Unfortunately the `ToString` method on the `List<>` type (which I believe is what `Console.WriteLine` calls) doesn't show what's in the list. It would be nice if `List<string>.ToString()` would call `ToString` on each of its elements, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the user types in the following: "Jake, Julia, Craig"

```
string[] memberlist = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
```

Eventually you need to .Trim() on every name cause of the whitespace after the comma.

Edit: For a "multiline" solution look at @Jeff Bridgman post.

Comment: I see no indication that the OP wants to use a comma-separated list of names.

Comment: Yeah, saw that too now. Linked to @Jeff Bridgman Solution. Although nothing speaks against a comma seperated input.